# Why is my Apple TV returning errors when I watch movies rented from Apple?

Tags: appletv, itunes-store

Movies start, but a few times per movie, returns an error: "An error occurred while loading this content".  It will allow me to start it again, but it's really frustrating.    Internet connection seems solid enough- movies in hd start almost instantly, and nothing else on the network hiccups when it occurs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you called Apple support? I'm having a similar issue with my Apple TV (2nd gen) - with a number of podcasts it comes up with this message, but it plays all other content correctly. Really a big pain. 

I'm just going through the support process at the moment, and they tell me my issue is unknown to them, but perhaps it's more widespread than they think.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with comcast internet. I believe their "speed boost" traffic shaping tricked the Apple TV into thinking I had something like a 22 megabit pipe - so the movies started playing instantly. When the boost expired, the data rate was much reduced and eventually the movie played past the delivery of the content which means my overall download wasn't fast enough to get the whole movie to my set before the movie ended.

When I changed internet providers the issues have been resolved for me. I stumbled on this by realizing I never got this error when taking my Apple TV to a friend's house with "slower" internet. The confusing part was most of the time - comcast was fast enough - but when it wasn't I still got a great initial "boost" but couldn't really watch the rental due to poor bandwidth.

Comment: I have also seem people saying this because comcast's dns was messing with their settings, and switching to 8.8.8.8 aka Google's DNS worked for their Apple TV.

Comment: I can't be sure DNS isn't involved - but generally when DNS is problematic - things are too slow to start or never start instead of degrading mid connection / mid stream. It's possible and a good suggestion when this error happens immediately on the initial play request - just pretty unlikely from the specifics of this question.

Comment: Yeah I know, its weird. Thats why I wouldnt even post it in an answer, its too disconnected for me to feel like it has a logical leap